# Python. How to replace everything in a string that is not in quotes

Tags: python, string, replace

how to replace everything in a string that is not in quotes python.
The string has a replacement method, but how to make it so that when replacing, for example, 1 with 2, 1, which is in quotes, is not replaced

I tried to do something like this with a for loop but it didn't work

Comment: You tried to do something like... what? Please [edit] your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146), *all as formatted text in the question itself.* Do not post images of text. The code should be a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just made this :

```
someText = " Some texte in quote 'The quote text' and other quote "
finalText = ""
splitedText = someText.split("'")
for idx, text in enumerate(splitedText):
    if not (idx % 2):
        text = text.replace("quote", "replace") # replace your text here
    finalText += text
```

It is hard for me to explaine this in english, so i let you try.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).